# reCaptcha doesnt appear in comment (manual or plugin)

Tags: comments, security, spam, captcha

I tried the following:

- https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-insert-Captcha-code-in-WordPress-theme-without-using-any-plugin
- https://codeforgeek.com/add-google-recaptcha-wordpress/
- https://pluginsforwp.com/blog/add-recaptcha-to-wordpress-comments/

But I can't get comments with recaptcha. I also tried also "reCaptcha by BestWebSoft" and nothing appears.

I am using News Talk Theme (child theme - active) https://wordpress.org/themes/news-talk/ that is from NewsUp theme (parent theme).

I tried "reCaptcha by BestWebSoft" with other themes (https://themesinfo.com/rehub-vendor-wordpress-magazine-theme-bmke/2/) and it works. But some also don't work for other theme https://themegrill.com/themes/colormag/. So maybe it is a theme issue?

So far, I've only tried with adding the code in the parent theme because the child does not have a `single.php` file. Is this the right way? Or how should I do it?

Here is a screenshot of my comment, there is no reCaptcha
[image: comment screen screenshot]

Comment: *So far, I'ved only tried with adding the code in the parent theme* -- please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/406808/edit) to include the code you've added. Also: as you're using a 3rd-party plugin for the CAPTCHA, you would probably be better off asking their support for assistance with this.

Answer (score 1):

As I see you are using reCaptcha v3 as the examples you try and it will not appear until the user score is under the minimum you added into the configuration but it is still working and checking the user score before he submits your form.

anyway if you configured the plugin correctly you may see the reCaptcha sticky button at the bottom right corner of your website

Comment: how do you know I am using reCaptcha v3. So far the site key and secret are v2.

Comment: I thought that because of the links you added to your questions and also all recommend using v3 nowadays anyway can you share the code you are using so we can check this together!

Comment: I use https://themegrill.com/themes/colormag/ with reCaptcha by BestWebSoft. it didnt work. any idea ?

Comment: another theme I use https://wordpress.org/themes/news-talk/, also didnt work. maybe you can easily install that and see ? pretty easy to setup with reCaptcha by BestWebSoft. so far I use is with recaptcha v2 with this.

Comment: I've tried and this is a testing website with new installation and it's working good for me
https://ahmedabdo.live/test/2022/06/23/test/

Comment: can you share your google recaptcha settings on google and the plugin options may there is something you missed